# What is the tolerated performance difference between HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, software-raid

I got a server with software RAID1 and two identical HDDs. Using `hdparm -tT` I get sligthly different results, one gives me 100Mb/s and the other one 97Mb/s. Is this difference tolerable in this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many factors that can affect drive performance, that variability with results from testing is imminent.  A 3Mb/s difference between the results is hardly worth worrying about.  Just as proof, for the SU blog I'm conducted HDD tests and here are some results:

[image]

[image]

as you can tell, there are differences in speeds, using the same program and same drive, with no other applications running.